# Not enough space on / to install new kernel update

Tags: kernel, filesystems, hard-disk, upgrade, root-filesystem

During a recent update I received this:

```
Installing: kernel-default-2.6.37.6-0.11.1 [error]
Installation of kernel-default-2.6.37.6-0.11.1 failed:
(with --nodeps --force) Error: Subprocess failed. Error: RPM failed:    installing package kernel-default-2.6.37.6-0.11.1.x86_64 needs 147MB on the / filesystem


Abort, retry, ignore? [a/r/i] (a): i
Installing: kernel-desktop-2.6.37.6-0.11.1 [error]
Installation of kernel-desktop-2.6.37.6-0.11.1 failed:
(with --nodeps --force) Error: Subprocess failed. Error: RPM failed:    installing package kernel-desktop-2.6.37.6-0.11.1.x86_64 needs 148MB on the / filesystem


Abort, retry, ignore? [a/r/i] (a): i
Installing: kernel-source-2.6.37.6-0.11.1 [error]
Installation of kernel-source-2.6.37.6-0.11.1 failed:
(with --nodeps --force) Error: Subprocess failed. Error: RPM failed:    installing package kernel-source-2.6.37.6-0.11.1.noarch needs 432MB on the / filesystem
```

Which I am assuming means my `/` partition needs some room. So I checked the size/space:

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1              25G   24G  208M 100% /
```

How did `/` grow to be so huge!? Is this a common occurrence and is there a quick trick to freeing up some space? I assume that there are things I'm not using in there and I've been able to update kernels easily for the past year -- so something is accumulating.

I'd rather figure out what I free up (are old kernels kept?) instead of re-partitioning my whole drive to grow `/`.

Comment: I don't know if this will help you, but with du you can find out which directories are largest. You probably want to use --max-depth=N and --human-readable   (-h)

Comment: @Bernhard: I don't know why I didn't think of this earlier... thanks mate. Post this as an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: I think you already got a more extensive answer

Comment: Most distros don't clean up old kernels by default.  It's been a while since I used an rpm distro, but I think `rpm -qf /lib/modules/*` might show you old kernels.

Comment: The version smells like linux. Here is a related question: http://askubuntu.com/q/52728/10068

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Make a backup before making any of the following changes***
Do not proceed without either a backup or the willingness to lose all data.

run

```
du -sh /home
```

to get the size used by /home directory.
If it's sufficiently large(>=4G), /home is a good candidate to have its own partition.

Boot from either a livecd or  [SystemRescueCd](http://www.sysresccd.org/Main_Page)
Depending on your partition table type (GPT or MBR), use either `gdisk`, `parted`, or `fdisk`.

Create a new partition
Format using your preferred fstype
e.g.

```
mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda2
mkdir /mnt/os
mkdir /mnt/home
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/os    # mount your OS, now all on /
mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/home  # mount newly formatted partion
cp -a /mnt/os/home/* /mnt/home/ # copy current /home data to new partition
cd /mnt/os/home                 # remove old home data, leaving mountpoint
rm -rf .
```

Now you need to cd to /mnt/os/etc and edit fstab and add

```
/dev/sda2 /home ext4 defaults 0 1
```

There's more than one way to do this. Depending on your experience and skill you could mount by UUID (preferred, but not necessary).

One could do the same for other filesystems, if you've installed a lot of google tools, or eclipse, they get intalled in /opt and it is also a good candidate to be in its own partition.

If you get to the point where you have many partitions, you'll want to switch to GPT partitioning and/or LVM. If so, re-ask the question

Comment: Thanks for the well written answer. `/home` is already in its own (200G) partition so that wasn't the issue. You're right though, it turned out that `/opt` had a fair amount of bulk. I removed some applications and freed around 10G.

Comment: you're welcome, I'm glad you solved your problem.  
my /usr is >6G and Arch complains with /usr on its own fs.  
This can be a real pain :(

Answer (score 1):

Whether a 25GB system partition is huge or tiny depends on how much software you have installed (is this a single-purpose server or a shared workstation with a lot of domain-specific software?) and on how much data is lurking in `/var` (do you have 200 users' mail in that partition?).

Good places to look for accumulated cruft include:

- `/tmp`: any old, large files in there? You may want to make `/tmp` a `tmpfs` filesystem, so that it doesn't consume disk space and starts afresh at every boot.
- `/var/tmp`: any huge files in there?
- `/var/log`: did a runaway service produce gigabytes of logs?
- `/var/cache`: is there a large cache that isn't being purged properly? Especially check where your distribution puts downloaded packages (e.g. `/var/cache/apt/archives/` on APT-based distributions).
- Do you have any unused software installed? That's usually not much, but you may be able to find library versions that aren't used by any executable still on your system. Programs like `deborphan` (on Debian and derivatives) can help. Check if you're encumbered by old kernels, too.

If you can't find what to delete, you can at least see what's taking up space with `du` or a [graphical alternative](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2045/how-to-determine-where-biggest-files-directories-on-my-system-are-stored) such as [Baobab](http://www.marzocca.net/linux/baobab/) (a Gnome utility).

If you have space left elsewhere, you can move some large chunk of `/usr` or `/var` (or `/opt` or `/srv` if relevant) to a different partition and make a symbolic link.